# Coloring a cell based on row and column header values in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, format, conditional-statements

I would like to color a cell based on the header and row values, not the cell value.  In the sample below, when `[ship_prom] = [produced_month]` the `[sum(wgt_scaled)]` cell should go green (marked by X in the example).

```
         [produced_month]   
[ship_prom]     [Sum(wgt_scaled)]   
          201812    201901  201902

201901      2.1       X       3

201902      1.5               X
```

Sorry if formatting doesn't work - tried pasting in an image but that failed too..

I tried conditional formatting of `[Sum(wgt_scaled)]` using `=iif(Fields!ship_prom.Value=Fields!produced_month.Value,"Green","No Color")`
but not all cells have values, and every null value cell turned green.

Additional from DonD:
  The actual report has several additional fields / groups, so your comment around it being in that area is appropriate.  I tried to simplify the report to just the basic data but still am not getting  the same output as you.
[reduced report info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H71zV.png)

@steve-o169 Since you are able to produce the report using the Switch, I'll go ahead and mark your answer as best.  Thanks for the help!

[design layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42I1f.png)

[sample desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAPJE.png)

[Actual data query and subset of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyhcg.png)

Comment: Then add an `AND value <> ""` to the condition.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work, as the intersection will always be null.  The actual report shows tons produced outside of scheduled month, with actual production on the top and scheduled on the left.  The dataset query is sum of tons when prod_month <> sched_month.

Comment: One more comment on the additional details provided--remove any line breaks from your expression just for the sake of eliminating any SSRS weirdness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add another conditional statement to account for `NULL` values.  But personally, I would suggest implementing a switch for better control.  Try the following expression.

```
=Switch(Fields!ship_prom.Value=Fields!produced_month.Value AND TRIM(Fields!ship_prom.Value) <> "","Green", 
true, "No Color")
```

EDIT: Might need to see the query before I can really figure out the problem at hand here.  I'm unable to reproduce your issue.  I've created a simple dataset with the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ship_prom INT, produced_month INT, wgt_scaled DECIMAL(2,1))
INSERT INTO #temp (ship_prom, produced_month, wgt_scaled)
VALUES (201901, 201812, 2.1), (201902, 201812, 1.5), (201901, 201901, NULL), 
(201902, 201901, NULL), (201901, 201902, 3.0), (201902, 201902, NULL)

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

I've laid out my table with a column group on `produced_month` and a row group on `ship_prom` and grouped by `ship_prom` with the following layout.

[image: design view]

Using the exact switch expression from my answer, I was able to achieve the following result.

[image]

Comment: Hi Steve,  that did not work either, as the ship_prom.value is null at the intersection.  I tried the switch formula, but none of the cells went green.

Comment: What do you mean by "null at the intersection"?

Comment: ship_prom = produced_month will never have a value.  other combinations may or may not have values, so I cannot test on state of the value, only on column header versus row header.

Comment: I can't understand the issue as you are describing it. If `ship_prom` and `produced_month` are always `NULL`, then you could just use `=IIF(Fields!ship_prom.Value Is Nothing, "Green", "No Color")`.  Please provide some of the data or sample data so that you can properly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: updated question to include data and align X spots appropriately

Comment: Ok, one last question -- what does the X represent?  Is it possible to simply check the `SUM([Sum(wgt_scaled)]` for a value instead of `ship_prom`?

Comment: X is just to show green color - actual cell would be empty

Comment: Hey @DonD, check my edit.  I'll probably need to see the query to accurately assess what is going wrong.  The issue is likely in the query or in the grouping on the `ship_prom` or `produced_month` fields.

Comment: As Steve-o169 has said we will need to see some sample data as it comes out of the dataset (not formatted in the report). I suspect that in the data there is no record where the two dates are the same, hence the null/blank in the report. If this is the case then you cannot compare the two null values as there is no record to actually test.

Comment: @Alan - you are absolutely correct - from the dataset, there will be no record to test - the column and row values come from other records - that's why I'm trying to compare the report header values, and not the cell values.